Fixing my multi-lunar/planetary System
So I'm working on a fictional system that is based on several habitable moons orbiting a Gas Giant. The Specifics are as follows:

Mass of the central Star (Currently): 3 Solar Masses

Mass of the Gas Giant: 11 Jupiter Masses

Semi Major Axis of the Host Planet: 7.75 AU

Mass of the Moons from inside to outside in Earth-Masses:

3 Moons posess 0.6

3 Moons posess 0.8

and the outermost 2 have 1.5 and 2 Earth Masses respectively


So my simulation is stable but, according to the answers to my previous post, not habitable. The reason seems to be that the star in my Simulation is too hot and massive and thus will burn away the moon's atmospheres. This being the case due to its hazardous UV-Radiation. I'm looking into 2 ways to fix it.
1. Change the Gas-Giant into a Brown Dwarf/failed Star and the Star type from a very luminous Type F/A star to a sun like G-Type or a smaller F-Type Star.
Pros:

Since the Brown Dwarf has a superior Mass compared to a gas giant,
it's hill sphere is bigger and thus I can fit in the number of moons
I desire.
Less UV-Radiation from the central star and thus an actual chance of life.
Sufficient Live Span of the Star.

Cons:

The Brown Dwarf emits x-Ray radiation and causes even bigger tidal heating
than the gas giant already seems to do (according to simulations in
Space Engine and Universe Sandbox)
In General, the hill sphere of the Gas-Giant/Brown Dwarf is getting
to small if i calculated it correctly.

2. Making up my own Star-Type
I could also resort to creating my own fictional/not yet discovered star class which would give me the total freedom to say stuff like "This star is super massive, super inflated, and more luminous but produces mainly infrared and only a small amount of UV-Radiation. Oh and it exists long enough in order for life to evolve because i say so"
Im posting the inner and the outer area of the lunar System below:


My Question is: Which option is best if I want both the best chances of the moons (except the innermost one) being habitable on the surface and being the most believable scenario for an average, can i say "not too nerdy" audience? For the "fictional Star Type" i would open up a new question if needed.

Take the "invent my own star type" option. I'm serious. That's the quintessence of worldbuilding. Sometimes we're too stuck on the desire to be so "realistic" that we can't look beyond what we know to be possible into the realm of what we think is impossible to discover a whole new boundary we never knew existed. All that begins with a good imagination. I love it.

Thank you for the Answer. So my follow up question would be: How does the climate differ on a specific moon from the climate on earth, assuming its day/night cycle is 39 Hours compared to the 24 hours on earth? Maybe its best to create a new question for that

That would definitely require a new question. It's also a very broad question and climate questions are the most difficult to answer because there are so many variables. You need to give us all the stats about the star, the moons and their parent planet, as well as a map of the target moon. With that we can give you general guidelines - climate is that difficult.

“Invent my own star type” really means “invent my own physics”. We know what kind of stars are possible in our universe, and super-massive long-lived stars with spectra peaking in infrared are not among them.

Plausibility of the scenario & options
Note: The following list highlights the most problematic aspects. But they also provide possible solutions, like if it says "radiation levels are too high" - you can make up some reasons to have that lowered, and move the whole thing closer to plausibility.
Moons Hazards
Sun's influence is surely a key-factor for the in-habitability, but not the only one to be considered.
A gas giant can be considered a proto-sun. If the giant had the opportunity to accumulate more mass, it could have had started fusioning, and becoming a sun himself.
Our Jupiter is already not that very far (in cosmic terms) from being able to start fusioning processes. A gas giant with 11 times its mass might cross that limit; Depends highly on the composition of gases and other materials making up the giant and the circumstances. It might happen, if it serves the plot; but it can also not happen, if not needed.
The gas giant most likely has a strong magnetic field and sends out high amounts of radiation himself (like our Jupiter does).
It might be plausible to have the magnetic field configured in a way to deflect radiation by the sun around the giant, thus protecting it (similar to the Van-Allen-Belt for earth).
A strong magnetic field of the gas giant combined with high amount of radiation, poses a hazardous environment for the moons. Especially for life.
To be habitable on the surface, moons need an atmosphere (unless we are talking about alien lifeforms, or something like sealed bases, potentially below the surface). Having an atmosphere (and a breathable at that) is very unlikely though, because of the general low mass of moons and their small sizes.
A decent atmosphere with (multiple) protective layers would also be able to shield against all sorts of radiation though (similar to the ozone-layer on earth).
There is a similar question on the minimal factors needed to preserve an atmosphere, which might be a good starting point. But it comes down to number crunching a whole lot, so I'd skip it probably.
Additionally, temperatures need to allow liquid water, or being at least close to a comfortable range (for humans). Almost all moons in our solar-system are deep frozen (did not check all of them). Surface temperatures of -200°C is not uncommon, especially when at the far side of the sun (behind the planet).
--> Seems like there has to be a high amount of terra-forming (or "moon-forming" ;)) going on, to have a somewhat plausible explanation for habitability.
Moon Days/Nights/Years
Revolving times of the moons play a major role on durations for a moon-year and a day/night-cycle. A moon-year (1 time around the planet) could be anything from a few earth-years to hundreds of years, implying different kinds of trouble for life.
Moons can rotate around an axis to have "something" like days/nights, but they also are common to show the same side to their main planet all the time (as our earth-moon does). In this case one moon-day/night-cycle would be the same length as revolving one time around the whole planet. Meaning a "day" is more like being months to years long, following by the same length as "night".
Most certainly a moon which rotates within hours, will not be able to sustain life at all. That would be more like a carousel rotating so fast that it throws off everybody (did not compute it).
The proximity to the gas giant would probably have it totally dominating the sky on the side facing the planet. Unless there is an atmosphere which can cover him up decently enough. I would not expect the sky to be nice and blue, though (unless created artificially for example).
--> A convenient constellation of rotation/revolving and positioning might be a solution too make some life-sustaining factors plausible in a "natural" way. But four moons that are habitable this way... is very improbable.
Conclusion
I have the impression, you want too much from your solar-system in terms of realism. To shift things towards higher plausibility I suggest reconsider certain aspects:
Accept that the moons are inhabitable, but alleviate it by other means. For example: going sub-surface, using artificial shielding, terraforming, use alien-lifeforms or bio-engineered life-forms specially adapted to the hazardous environments, maybe a high tech-level can also help, or add some magic/spiritual intervention, maybe just one habitable moon would also suffice? (list is not exhaustive, imagination unlimited here).
Computing everything down to the very last detail and still end up with the fictionally intended characteristics seems to be infeasible. So, I would agree with @JBH: Emphasis should be to create a plot supporting world on the fictional-level, not on the scientific-level. A few pointers on major aspects to keep track of when considering solar-system-mechanics, were provided here hopefully.

Don't make up a new kind of star!  They're not exactly hiding, you know.  I mean, not unless you want this to be THE defining feature of a one-of-a-kind system, or you set it in a parallel universe, etc.
The other option is better.  Red dwarf planets like TRAPPIST-1 are still the topic of research and debate.  I don't think you're forced to assume a brown dwarf planet must be uninhabitable.  A simulation is only a guess at this point.
My preference is the original scenario.  By the mass-luminosity relationship, your gas giant is a bit cooler than Earth; perhaps its internal heat makes up the difference.  So the only question is whether hard radiation strips off the moons' atmospheres.  Maybe it would -- if they were planets.  But being moons, they are deep in a gravity well - any atmosphere lost could end up in a gas torus like for Io and Europa, and might deposit back again on the same moon, or perhaps another (as on Iapetus).  The gas giant might also lose atmosphere that deposits onto the moons.  There's sure to be no data on this, because nobody has proven the existence of even a single exomoon anywhere in the cosmos, let alone studied the atmosphere of a super-Jupiter and multiple moons.  Remember: no data means you get to speculate whichever way seems most entertaining.  There's a risk that you'll write a Venus-with-swamps story tinged by wishful thinking, but honestly, aren't those still fun to read even after we know better?

It seems the main problem is balancing the mass of the central star with its energy output to get the correct hill radius and the correct energy level at the planet. It might be worth investigating making the central star a close coupled binary, with the gas giant orbiting both some way out.
That way you might be able to have two stars each with half the mass (or some other convenient adjustable fraction to suit). That way you should get a less intensive radiation environment for the same total central mass.
Unfortunately I do not have the time or experience necessary to do all of the relevant calculations.
